# Opengl: Can we calculate how much percentage of object is shadowed by other object in the scene?

Tags: opencv, opengl, shadow, transform-feedback

We are making a simulation of city with lot of buildings. We have requirement to calculate how much percentage of building surface is of directly illuminated by sunlight(direct-light). Is there any feasibility read pixels of shadow and calculate this? We have tried rendering of objects render to texture and reading no pixels in shadow. However this values differ on camera angle , seems not reflecting real values and cannot calculate overall percentage. Can any one suggest alternate / better approach to this overall problem. Can we use latest such technologies such as transform feedback?
Thanks

Comment: Did you already research shadowing algorithms? What did you find? Why are the obvious hits like [shadow-mapping](https://www.google.com/search?q=opengl+shadow) not sufficient?

Comment: Shadow mapping works very good for visualisation. I could not think that system enables to *calculate* How much percentage of building is covered by shadow. (Basically to estimate efficiency of solar clean energy for particular building). I decided make use of  ray-casting for this.